# How to redirect user to the Slack auth page to login and grant permissions to the python script

Tags: python, parsing, request, slack, slack-api

I'm creating a python application, to backup chat history from Slack.

I've tested all API features with my test access token. But i want to know how can i authorise in Slack with login, password and workspace name, like on the screenshoot.

[image]

I've digged in the API docs but every time they tell me to create an app in my own Slack account. I can't understand, how to implement this authorisation redirect...

So, the main question is how to authorise user and grant permissions to the python script after user just pus the button in my desktop application. Where should i redirect him?

**UPD**: Here is why i have the questions. This is the dialog window when i try to create an App:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to authenticate with Slack API from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299405/how-to-authenticate-with-slack-api-from-server)